# I've lost my ID, will I still be able to travel?

Tags: air-travel, uk, paperwork, eu-citizens, ryanair

My wallet and ID were stolen, and I have a Ryanair flight in two days. I don't have time to get a new one (national holiday tomorrow). Will I be able to travel with Ryanair with a scanned copy or a "replacement document" (a paper with the same data as the ID, issued by the government for use in the meantime it takes for the actual card to arrive)? I can also bring a police report stating I had my wallet stolen.

That is, will I be able to clear the Ryanair boarding check and the entry passport check? I'm travelling inside the EU (to the UK and back).

I'm a Portuguese citizen.

Comment: Portugal, national ID card.

Comment: You might consider changing the title of your question to something like "I've lost my ID, will I still be able to travel?" They way it's worded, I thought Ryanair was responsible for losing your ID while they had it in their possession (for some reason).

Comment: In Spain I think you need to go to the police department and set a denouncement. Explain them everything and with that I think you are good to go. This can usually be done at the airport also, and they'll be familiar with this situation

Comment: I would get an emergency ID or passport...I had once a passport issued in 3h, but was in an embassy abroad. I think there are similar arrangements here.

Comment: See [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/97786/64737) - same thing happened to me a couple of months back. It was even with Ryanair. I'm sorry to tell you this, but you have to accept that you are not flying this time. There aren't any hacks or workarounds. Just try to recoup what money you can, and rearrange your trip when you have your passport or ID back.

Comment: Unfortunate situations like this is why a traveller's insurance with a cancellation policy is a good idea.

Comment: First file a Police complaint and show that to authorities. thats the first step!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others stated, you won't make it without an Id, so your best bet is to request a new ID.
A Portuguese ID can be requested with very high urgency. You can do it today and still get it today or Friday (depending on your flight schedule it might work), plus it's close enough from the airport to just go there directly after (assuming you're in Lisbon).

https://www.portaldocidadao.pt/web/instituto-dos-registos-e-do-notariado/cartao-de-cidadao  See "custo"

You will pay 50 Euros but it might be worth it.

You can request/make it in any "citizen shop"/loja do cidadadão but you will have to get the physical card  at "justice campus"/campus da justiça in Parque das Nações, Lisbon. Again, assuming you're in Lisbon, since you have to get it there I would just go there directly ASAP. They're open until 19h.

Also, they will give you a receipt that allows you to drive. At least that happens in a regular renewal since they keep your old ID. I am not sure that paper would work for flying as well. You might want to ask there just as plan B.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing that and I can pick up the ID tomorrow. I ended up paying 88 Euro for it, which is a lot for a replacement ID, but I really couldn't risk ending up getting barred entry in the UK and/or having to pay a huge fine, nevermind full cost of the hotel, etc.

Answer (score 40):

You have a bigger problem than "will Ryanair let me fly" but rather "will I be admitted to the UK". To be admitted to the UK, you must usually have a passport, or an EEA national identity card. You don't have either, which makes admission difficult. You would only be admitted if you can convince the Border Officer of your EU citizenship. If you aren't admitted, Ryanair will be fined, and forced to take you back to wherever you came from. Ryanair won't take the risk of this happening. You won't be allowed to fly.

Comment: I would agree, in principle, with your answer. However, if the OP can get the "replacement document" issued in time, that _might_ work for him. For example (in the US), we get a temporary, paper license plate to mount to our car while the state is busy processing paperwork and making the permanent one. You can even drive a car without a plate at all if you've just purchased it from a private seller-you need to carry proof of the sale transaction (and various other docs), and will likely get pulled over more than once for not having a plate, but you can show cause and ownership you'll be OK

Comment: @FreeMan it specifically depends on what the temporary document is and if it is accepted by UK immigration in lieu of an EEA identity card.  If there is *any* doubt here at all, Ryanair simply wont let them board as there is too much risk involved for them.

Comment: @FreeMan Temporary car papers are a poor example, as they often work only inside the country. When I bought my car, I remember being specifically told not to drive abroad until I get permanent license plates.

Comment: @Moo - Your points are entirely valid, as are the points in this answer. Since this answer is currently the most upvoted, I simply wanted to point out that there were no legal references to support the unconditional "You won't be allowed to fly" statement at the end. I agree that it's highly likely that this is true, but I don't believe it's quite as definitive as it sounds, so I don't want the OP to give up all hope based on that statement. There may be other possibilities worth pursuing.

Comment: @FreeMan That’s a fair criticism. I would stick by the assessment, assuming that the asker only brings a photocopy of their ID and a police report. If they manage to obtain some kind of temporary ID card, then I’d give them a slim chance of boarding. I would tell them to phone Ryanair, but I’m sure that whoever answers the phone would tell them that they must bring the proscribed forms of ID, without exception.

Comment: @MJeffryes - agreed. The other two answers _do_ give alternatives, including being able to get a freshly minted Portuguese ID in a very short time frame. In the US, you could probably get a temporary, paper driver's license same-day (on a work day - weekend? forget it!), and that would work for most, if not all driving and ID related needs.

Comment: Thank you, I ended requesting an urgent ID which I can pick tomorrow. I ended up paying 88 Euro for it, which is a lot for a replacement ID, but I really couldn't risk ending up getting barred entry in the UK and/or having to pay a huge fine, nevermind full cost of the hotel, etc.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't think it's just that the state is "busy processing paperwork and making new plates," unless maybe you have custom ones. When mine were stolen some years ago, the state's office had some actual plates on hand that I was able to put on my car the same day. Which makes me think it has more to do with the dealer submitting everything and what have you, or possibly with ownership transfer requiring more red tape. Replacing a stolen set is obviously more analogous here, of course.

Comment: @jpmc26 Indiana used to do that too, but now they hand you a more sturdy paper plate them mail the metal one to you. Anyway, we've veered way OT, so time to bail.

Answer (score 16):

I can only answer to you how the situation in Switzerland and the Netherlands is. You are able to aquire an emergency passport at the airport, when you lose your ID or passport or when it has been stolen. Be sure to arrive a couple of hours earlier than normally, because you probably won't be the only one having that issue.

**Take the following things with you:**

1. Flight Tickets
2. Hotel reservation
3. Some kind of document from your village, where they state, who you are
4. A copy of your stolen ID card
5. The police report
6. If you have already ordered a new ID, take a copy of the ordering conformation with you
7. Drivers licence or some other official card
8. A picture which is complient with the picture rules for ID cards
9. About 50-150 Euro

[This is the goverment website for an emergency passport at Zürich Airport in German](https://ds.zh.ch/internet/sicherheitsdirektion/de/themen/pass/provisorischer_pass.html)

[And the one in dutch for Amsterdam Schiphol](https://www.defensie.nl/onderwerpen/noodpaspoort/aanvragen-noodpaspoort)

Comment: I did exactly this on an airport in Sweden when I thought that UK was a Schengen member so neglected to bring my passport - oops. Got a temporary passport made in 30 minutes. I _did_ however have a valid Swedish ID card, although that was the only information they needed.

Comment: @pipe Your Swedish ID card would have been sufficient to enter the UK. The UK accepts all EU national ID cards as it is required to by EU law.

Comment: @MJeffryes This was over 15 years ago, the laws may have changed.

Comment: @pipe It can't have been much over fifteen years ago; Sweden only joined Schengen sixteen years ago (25 March 2001, to be precise).

Comment: @MikeScott Yep, it was in July that same year, IIRC